# Facing problem in if- else statement. It always redirect to 1st condition

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my PHP code. In the If-else statement when I login it always goes to the 1st php page. It does not go to the other. Suppose If I type username 'tamluk' it redirects to 'welcomemoyna.php'. I want when username match it will redirect to the definite page.

I am trying it online. 000webhost for PHP and PHPMyAdmin for the database.

```
<?php

session_start();
$message = "";
if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id8401317_new', 'Deba@212', 'id8401317_abc') or die('Unable To connect');
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '" . $_POST["password"] . "'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if (is_array($row)) {
        $_SESSION["id"] = $row[id];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $row[username]; {
            if (isset($_POST["username"]) == 'moyna') {
                header("Location:welcomemoyna.php");
            } elseif (isset($_POST["username"]) == 'ramtarak') {
                header("Location:welcomeramtarak.php");
            } elseif (isset($_POST["username"]) == 'tamluk') {
                header("Location:welcometamluk.php");
            } elseif (isset($_POST["username"]) == 'bagnan') {
                header("Location:welcomebagnan.php");
            }
        }
    } else {
        $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
    }
// }
}
?>
```

I want that when I type for 'username' like `tamluk` it will redirect to `welcometamluk.php` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

your user values now in a session.try this.i hope it will help.

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $message="";
        if(count($_POST)>0) {
         $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','id8401317_new','Deba@212','id8401317_abc') or die('Unable To connect');
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
        $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if(is_array($row)) {
        $_SESSION["id"] = $row[id];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $row[username];
        if (isset($_SESSION['username']['id'])) {
                    if($_SESSION["username"]=='moyna') {
        header("Location:welcomemoyna.php");
        }
        elseif($_SESSION['username']=='ramtarak') {
        header("Location:welcomeramtarak.php");
        }
        elseif($_SESSION['username']=='tamluk') {
        header("Location:welcometamluk.php");
        }
        elseif($_SESSION['username']=='bagnan') {
        header("Location:welcomebagnan.php");
        }
        }
        else {
        $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
        }
        }
        }
    ?>
```